# Deleting Azure Active Directory returns Delete all App registrations although there is no app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to delete an Active Directory *(not default)* in Azure. It said I need to ***Delete all App registrations***. When I click on the link, there is no registered app.

Interesting is dashboard said I have 1 app registered. When I click on the link, there is no app either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if  you have any additional service principals in that directory.

Comment: Hi, May I know if your issue has been resolved?

Comment: In my case I was able to find one more app under Azure AD B2C which were not listed on app registrations blade, after deleting it I was able to delete directory

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar situation today and got to this post.

I have found solution accidentally by following one of the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-api).
This article is about adding new application and that's how I got to understand how to find all registered applications.

Basically, this happened because there are two places where application registrations are shown.

**One**

Under "Azure Active Directory" -> "App Registrations".

**Second**

Under left navigation -> "All Services" -> Search for "Azure AD B2C" -> click on it -> Open.

Then you will be able to see "Applications".

[image: Here is the snapshot of how it looks like]

Here all your application which are using your Azure B2C instance are listed.  You will have to delete them.

Once they are deleted, you can again go to "Delete Directory" option and all your checks / pre requisites should be successful.

This helped me to resolve exact same issue and hoping that this should also help you.

Comment: There's one app "local" is listed in my B2C, but I cannot see the detail of the app (when I click it, the view goes on the details page but the loading will never complete). How do I delete this app?

Comment: Can you try deleting the app via powershell or bash prompt / cloud shell ?

Comment: I've tried the commands suggested by @Wayne already, but the app still exists there.

Comment: You can try "az ad app delete --<<aplication-id>>" command from the cloud shell.  It should delete the app registration for you.  Then try deleting the Azure AD instance.

Comment: It worked with creating a new subscription! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help !

Answer (score 4):

You may also have to remove additional service principals. Use Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell to remove all service principals. To do this, follow these steps:

Open Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell.
Connect to the Microsoft Online Service.

Run the following command:

```
Get-MsolServicePrincipal | Remove-MsolServicePrincipal
```

Note You may receive an error when you remove some service principals. These principals can’t be removed. However, this does not prevent you from deleting your directory.

The error that you receive may resemble the following:
`Remove-MsolServicePrincipal : Invalid value for parameter. Parameter Name: appPrincipalId`.

Also, you can use ARM powershell as following command:

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal | Remove-AzureRmADServicePrincipal
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Number of services before removing and after removing are same. `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal | Remove-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` did not remove any service, and I'm still seeing `Delete all App registrations`.

Comment: Hi,@Win .  Can you use Azure AD powershell 2.0 with `Get-AzureADApplication` to check if there is additional app in your directory?

Comment: Correct command is `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal | % { Remove-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $_.Id -Force }`
Of course, `-Force` is optional

Comment: I am having the same issue but cannot use MsolServices since my Azure account is a personal account and not a work/school account.  Any other ideas to delete app registrations?

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
Connect-AzureAD -Tenant id <string>
```

to learn application's object id

```
Get-AzureADApplication
```

then

```
Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <srtring>
```